# After adding HttpHeaders to the HttpClient.post POST never gets called

Tags: angular, cors

I have a method called apiCall that I use for all of my API calls in Angular

It looks like this:

```
apiCall(type: string, path: string, params: string[], data?: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log(API_URL + '/' + path);
    let result = new Observable();
    if (params.length) {
        for (const param of params) {
            path += '/' + param;
        }
    }

    // Add X-TenantId header
    // const tenantId = environment.tenantId;
    // const headers = tenantId ? new HttpHeaders({'X-TenantId': tenantId}) : null;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'X-TenantId': 'tenantId'});

    if (type === 'get') {
        result = this.http.get(API_URL + '/' + path, {headers: headers});
    } else if (type === 'post') {
        result = this.http.post(API_URL + '/' + path, data, {headers: headers});
    } else if (type === 'delete') {
        result = this.http.delete(API_URL + '/' + path, {headers: headers});
    } else if (type === 'put') {
        result = this.http.put(API_URL + '/' + path, data, {headers: headers});
    } else if (type === 'patch') {
        result = this.http.patch(API_URL + '/' + path, data, {headers: headers});
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }

    return result.pipe(
        tap((response: ApiResponse) => {
            console.log(response);
            return {...response};
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError())
    );
}
```

After adding X-TenantId as HttpHeaders, my POST request never gets executed in my browser (only OPTIONS request that gets 200 as response).

When I look at the network tab, it seems like browser tries to send my POST request before the OPTIONS one (at least that's the order I see in network tab), but the actual POST request never gets sent (I see this "Provisional headers are shown" and it says CORS error)

When I remove the X-TenantId header everything seems fine (first OPTIONS request is sent, then POST and everything works fine).

Comment: Because you're including custom header `X-TenantId` in a cross-origin request, the request will be [preflighted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests). You'll need to configure the server for CORS in order to allow such requests to be sent by your client from within browsers.